# how to print URLs to the MATLAB Command Window and open them in default browser

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to print URLs into MATLAB's command window. this is one simple solution but it does have a downside:

```
disp('This is a link to <a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>.')
```

Problem is that MATLAB opens this link in matlab's browser. I want the printed link to open in my system default browser. any suggestion? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more generic way, which should work on all platforms would be to use the MATLAB [`web`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/web.html) function. With the `-browser` option, the URL is opened in the system's default web browser.

In a `disp` command, this would be

```
disp('This is a link to <a href="matlab:web(''http://www.google.com'',''-browser'')">Google</a>.');
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that works for windows:

```
disp('This is a link to <a href="matlab:dos(''explorer http://www.google.com'');">Google</a>.')
```

Now if you click on it, the link will be opened in your default browser.

Comment: Nice answer, you may want to add a semicolon after the closing parenthesis. Otherwise matlab prints `"ans= 1"` after you click the link.

Comment: Thanks for the hint ;-) @MohsenNosratinia